# xamarin ContentPage: determine previous page from where it is called

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am calling common page which lists all distributors. when I select Item from list, I want to show next page based on from where List Page is called.

In Short calling  ListPage from Page A, Page B and Page C.

- If calling ListPage from Page A, upon ItemSelection, open PageA1,
- If calling ListPage from Page B, upon ItemSelection open PageB1.

Just can't determine my previous page/ can I use `this.Parent` method? how?

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Xamarin and was having a similar problem. What helped me was using the [Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlycollection-1.count?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_IReadOnlyCollection_1_Count) and [Item[Int32]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlylist-1.item?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_IReadOnlyList_1_Item_System_Int32_) properties of the [ModalStack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.inavigation.modalstack?view=xamarin-forms), but [NavigationStack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.inavigation.navigationstack?view=xamarin-forms) is also of type [IReadOnlyList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlylist-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) and has the same properties. So maybe something like:

```
var previousPageIndex = Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2;
var previousPageType = Navigation.NavigationStack[previousPageIndex];

if (previousPageType.Equals(Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage)) {
    Navigation.pushAsync(Page1);
} else if (previousPageType.Equals(PROJECT.DIR.CustomNavigationPage)) {
    Navigation.pushAsync(Page2);
}
```

NOTE: Checking `previousPageType` doesn't help if you're getting to your current page from 2 different pages of the same type.  In my actual scenario, I was either in a ModalStack or not, so I just had to check if `ModalStack.Count > 0` to determine whether to pop back a page or to switch tabs.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain ***how*** those helped you to solve the problem? That would make your answer a lot more useful for future Googlers.

Answer (score 0):

Got the work around as passing parameter to main ContentPage's class constructor with default value. Assigning that value to class field and checking with it.
Please let me know if anyone has better solution :)

```
class DistributorListX : ContentPage
{
   public string previousPage;
   public DistributorListX(string PreviousPage="")
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        previousPage = PreviousPage;
    }
   void listItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
   {
        if (previousPage=="A")
           Navigation.PushAsync(A1);
        else
           Navigation.PushAsync(A2);

   }
}
```